# Filling empty squares in a R-Heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I want to plot on a heatmap a continuous variable (called *value*) depending on the day and the hour.

I show the **header** of my data.frame:

```
> data
        value hour       day
1   4.0775374   17    martes
2   5.9107966   13    martes
3   3.9318256   12    martes
4   2.9444390   10    martes
5   4.9767337   17     lunes
6   3.7841896   13     lunes
7   4.9904326   11     lunes
8   3.1780538   20   domingo
9   2.9444390   19   domingo
10  3.6635616   16   domingo
11  2.7080502   14   domingo
12  2.8903718   21    sábado
13  2.0794415   15    sábado
14  4.3944492   14    sábado
15  2.1972246   12    sábado
16  2.0794415   12    sábado
17  1.9459101   11    sábado
18  4.3694479   19   viernes
19  3.5835189   11   viernes
20  2.9957323   19    jueves
21  2.4849066   15    jueves
22  3.7376696   13    jueves
23  2.1972246   11    jueves
24  2.0794415   10    jueves
25  5.6664267   20 miércoles
26  6.1800167   18 miércoles
..  ...         .. .......
186 2.5649494   13   domingo
```

**R code:**

```
ggplot(data = data,aes(x=day, y=hour, fill=value)) + 
geom_tile() + 
scale_fill_continuous(low = 'yellow', high = 'blue')+
theme_classic()
```

**Output:**

[image: HeatmapR]

**Problem:** I need to fill empty squares (**not NA values**) with black colour squares in the heatmap.

**Solution:**

```
data = data %>% complete(hour, nesting(day))
```

Later, adding `na.value = 'color'` to `scale_fill_continuous` function.

Comment: You could color the whole panel in as black using `panel.background` in `theme`.  Alternatively you could expand the dataset so all combinations of `date` and `hour` are present (but missing are NA).  You could use something like `tidyr::complete` for the latter option.

Comment: Thanks a lot @aosmith. I have never used this library, but I knew it. Solution: data %>%  complete(hour, nesting(day)) and adding na.value = 'color' to scale_fill_continuous function.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there! Just add `na.value = 'salmon'` or whatever color you like in `scale_fill_continuous` like this:

```
ggplot(data = data,aes(x=day, y=hour, fill=value)) + 
geom_tile() + 
scale_fill_continuous(low = 'yellow', high = 'blue', na.value = 'salmon')+
theme_classic()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my data.frame doesn't have NA values. When I say empty squares, I mean to those days and hours that have no value for the continuous variable.

Comment: Not contemplated in the dataframe. For example, (day="domingo",hour="day") doesn't exist in my data.frame